# P(X= 1 | X+Y=9) with Poisson Distribution (X,Y independent)

Tags: probability, statistics, poisson-distribution

When trying to calculate the value of $P(X= 1 | X+Y=9)$, I tried doing:

$P(X= 1 | X+Y=9) = \frac{P(X=1\cap X+Y=9)}{P(X+Y = 9)} = \frac{P(X=1)P(Y=8)}{P(X+Y = 9)} $, but I'm constantly getting an incorrect answer.

Could someone shed some light on this?

Comment: what are the values that you obtained? what is the correct answer? what are the  parameters values? I think we need more details to debug.

Comment: I'm just asking if my simplification of the formula is correct, unless that depends on the values you just asked for.

Comment: For what it's worth, the approach is correct. You may want to use the fact that $X+Y$ is Poisson distributed (with the "right" parameter) to compute the denominator.

Answer (score 1):

The simplification is correct.

You just used $P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$ and $P(AB)=P(A)P(B)$ if $A$ and $B$ are independent.

You have to look for other factors, including potential computational mistake such as when you evaluate $P(X+Y=9)$ or perhaps a mistake in the answer key.

Remark:

$$\frac{P(X=1)P(Y=8)}{P(X+Y=9)}=\frac{u_1\cdot \frac{u_2^8}{8!}}{\frac{(u_1+u_2)^{9}}{9!}}=\binom91\left( \frac{u_1}{u_1+u_2}\right)\left( 1-\frac{u_1}{u_1+u_2}\right)^8$$

Comment: The formula I used for P(X+Y = k) is $$\frac{e^{-(u_1+u_1)}(u_1+u_2)^k}{k!}$$, given that $u_1, u_2$ are the parameter values for the Poisson distributions of X and Y

Comment: that seems fine.